# Cross-domain ajax in IE 8,9

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, cross-domain

I have an ajax request

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: url,
   success: function(xml) {
        $('.post-msg').append(processXml(xml, config));
   },
   error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       var errorMsg = "Request on url: " + url + " failed: " + textStatus + " error:" + errorThrown;
            alert(errorMsg);
        }
    });
```

The problem is that it does not work in IE 8,9 and boss proposed using post message. What are the ways to make this request worked in IE 8,9 ?

Answer (score 2):

How to do cross domain requests for CORS-enabled websites in IE8/9 is talked about [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx?__hstc=13789032.64e290a1d89c5e3131ed4c7d640ad511.1373379835966.1373379835966.1373379835966.1&__hssc=13789032.1.1373379835967), basically involves using **IE-unique** object [*XDomainRequest*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead of [*XMLHttpRequest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

You can see a code example on the [msdn *XDomainRequest* page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28VS.85%29.aspx)

```
// 1. Create XDR object 
var xdr = new XDomainRequest(); 
// 2. Open connection with server using GET method
xdr.open("get", "http://www.contoso.com/xdr.aspx");
// 3. Send string data to server
xdr.send();
```